# PHP - Remove the Specific Segment from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, openx

I have showing the ad banners in `.../openx/banner.php`

Each Banner I had set the Banner Link.

After clicking the Banners the Page is redirected with the following URL.

```
.../openx/www/delivery/ck.php?oaparams=2__bannerid=1__zoneid=1__cb=5b97a864fe__oadest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
```

Here is the root URL : `openx/`

I want to remove the last segment that is `oadest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com` when the page is loaded.

Please anyone help me...

Thanks...

Comment: Read about [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) Location

Comment: @Itay Openx is external source of my application... My server doesnt support to pass URL in Segments of URL. Can u help me how we can achieve this goal through `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Is this string always at the end of the url?

Comment: Yes Itay. It is always be in end of url...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this string is always at the end of your url, try putting this in the appropriate place on your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)oadset=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?ck\.php$ /ck.php?%1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for ur time Itay... I have placed into .htaccess file... But it shows the following error...`Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /projects/openx/www/delivery/ck.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: When you delete these rows from the file, can you access this url?

Comment: If i delete the specific segment from URL `oadest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com` by hardcode from address, It works good Itly.

Comment: I can't see the problem...  Sorry